# HQL Left Outer Join in case of two non Relational Objects

Tags: hibernate, join, hql

I have two tables which don't have any relationship, I would like to write `HQL` to get the results, Below is my `HQL` query

```
SELECT P.prcCatIdNo ,P.prcClsCd , 
  P.prcTypCd ,P.catIdNm ,P.boxQty ,P.prcUmAbr ,P.sellPrc 
  FROM Table1 P LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 L ON P.prcCatIdNo = L.ident
```

But i am getting the below exception

```
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join!
```

Could anyone please help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need Hibernate 5.1 to use ad hoc joins.

[Join unrelated entities in JPA](http://blog.anthavio.net/2016/03/join-unrelated-entities-in-jpa.html)

Or you can use `cross join`:

```
SELECT P.prcCatIdNo, P.prcClsCd, 
  P.prcTypCd, P.catIdNm, P.boxQty, P.prcUmAbr, P.sellPrc 
  FROM Table1 P, Table2 L where P.prcCatIdNo = L.ident
```

It is an `inner join`.

Looks like the join is senseless, because of you don't get any column from `Table2`.